Is it possible to make PlotHighlighting work with Callout?
New Mathematica enable PlotHighlighting automatically in Plot. For example
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6}]


You can pickup any x,y coordinate on the curve dynamically which is convenient.
However, if we use Callout like
Plot[Callout[Sin[x], "Sin[x]"], {x, 0, 6},PlotHighlighting -> "XYLabel"]


than PlotHighlighting does not work even setting PlotHighlighting explicitly.
So is it possible to make PlotHighlighting work with Callout?

Update
I think I probably found a bug in Mathematica 14.
In the doc, it says

PlotHighlighting->All will include the default highlighting, but may
interfere with other elements:

and there is an example
Plot[Callout[2 Sin[x] + x, "label", 8], {x, 0, 15}, 
 PlotHighlighting -> All]

I tried this, the PlotHighlighting works in Mathematica 13.3, But not working in Mathematica 14!

Show[Plot[Callout[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 6}], Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6}]]

Or slightly shorter, Show[Plot[#[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 6}] & /@ {Callout, Identity}]

@BobHanlon neat solution! Thank you so much!

An alternative is to use Highlighted:
Plot[Callout[Highlighted[Sin[x], "Ball"], "Sin[x]"], {x, 0, 6}]



Great! Thank you so much!
